# Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо найти круги на изображении и выделить их цветом, как возможно это реализовать?

Tags: python, компьютерное-зрение

[image: Изображение]

Само изображение изначально дано с сильным волновым зашумлением и окружностями с неровными границами.

В результате нужно вывести изображение с отмеченными цветом кругами / отмеченными областями с данными окружностями.

Пытался сделать это с помощью OpenCV, однако программа не видит окружности из-за их неровных очертаний

Comment: Что Вы использовали в OpenCV?

Answer (score 0):

Я подобную задачу решал в сфере гидроакустики. Искал покрышки на гидролокационных изображениях с ГБО. Использовал дескриптор HOG, бинарный классификатор - SVM. Вырезал некоторое множество изображений с покрышками и множество побольше - без. Затем обучил классификатор.
Был курьезный момент - на одном изображении классификатор нашел больше покрышек, чем я нашел их глазами.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Исходный код - https://github.com/sm7-cv-course/object_detection